# New to Linux: Download/Installing Debian

Tags: linux, installation, debian, iso-image, bittorrent

I've download Debian from Debian.org, first I got debian-7.8.0-amd64-i386-netinst.iso from the main page. I've made a bootable usb and when I selected the option Graphical Install it went black forever and ever, no response of any kind.

I'm checking the Debian site for another .iso, but I'm overwhelmed with the options, I know I have amd64, for example I'm checking the full download on cd/dvd with bittorrent but it shows debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-1.iso.torrent and debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-2.iso.torrent till CD 8, and kde lxde.
Can someone explain this to me? Do I need to download all the CD.X.iso.torrents?

Comment: you could try again but do not choose Graphical install this time. To check if your hardware is supported you could try to boot some so called Live-Distribution. If this works without problems then it is very likely that you can manage to run standard debian on your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

From the [site](https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/):

> The first CD/DVD disk contains all the files necessary to install a standard Debian system.

The terms kde, lxde, xfce refer to different Window Managers for Linux (the user interface and some other bits). If you don't have any special requirements, I suggest you just go with the standard version `debian-7.8.0-amd64-CD-1.iso`.

Comment: Another thing, I've downloaded it and made the Debian USB but when I select Graphic Install the monitor goes black and won't move from there. Is there any fix or something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Must be some problem with the graphics driver. You can try messing with kernel options at the very first stages of boot to try and select a different video mode. But I would just use the text installer if I were you.